# nginx: upstream not working

Tags: nginx, url

I'm having a problem with my upstream. I'm getting back the url `http://backend/f?p=4550` with a 404 error when I pass `https://secure.toto02.com/ords/pls/manitou/4550`. What I'm trying to do is keep `https://secure.toto 02.com/ords/pls/manitou/4550` in the navigator while the upstream sends the request to `http://192.167.1.79:8080/ords/f?p=4550`. I want to keep the request hidden.

I don't know what's wrong with the nginx server config file.Can anyone help?

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.167.1.79:8080;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name   secure.toto02.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;


    location  ~ "^/(.*)/pls/ords/(\d{1,4})$" {
        proxy_pass http://backend/ords/f?p=$2;        
    }
 }
```

Comment: Add "proxy_set_header Host $host;" and "proxy_redirection off" inside the location directive to keep the main url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using variables within the `proxy_pass` directive which makes your upstream server redirections to be directly forwarded to the client since nginx can't guess what to do. That's why you get this result in your browser.

Make sure your upstream server correctly answers to `http://192.167.1.79:8080/ords/f?p=4550` using exactly the same context than what nginx is doing.

For instance here at least two things are going wrong :

- You forgot to replace the `Host` header with your real domain so nginx is using `Host: backend` instead.
- Your upstream server is redirecting `/ords/f?p=4550` to (based on your comment) `/ords/f?p=4550:1:`.

Comment: The thing is that i need the **4550** part to be able to change depending on the value of the url `http://192.167.1.79:8080/ords/f?p=4550` how can i set it properly?

Comment: @skip87 Yes and ? Did you actually read the answer or expect one with a copy/paste solution ? Not going to happen.